# Load fonts in firefox web extension

Tags: font-face, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to port my chrome extension to firefox, but I'm having a hard time loading fonts in content scripts.
I have my font files bundled with the extension, then I load the content script with css that is trying to load fonts, however I'm getting an error like this

```
Security Error: Content at https://github.com/roberthovsepyan may not load or link to moz-extension://019740cc-47f5-44fd-bd62-f715c7e8e18c/c73abe648eae6ea7e72f.woff.
```

It works fine with in chrome and has been for many years. But for some reason in firefox it just won't work. I have the fonts in my web_accessible_resources in the manifest file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In Firefox the URL is dynamic and you must use chrome.runtime.getURL to get it.

Comment: I am. The url is correct, it's not the problem. The problem is the font is getting blocked by the security policy.

Comment: It's a bug in Firefox then.

Comment: https://bugzil.la/1267027. Try embedding your font as a `data:` URL inside the css file.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, doesn't work either unfortunately

Comment: You'll have to inject that css file as a content script, not a link element.

Comment: I am. I am actually using shadow-dom, so the css ends up inside a style tag inside the shadow dom.

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. You're adding the style as DOM content, but you should add it via `css` key in `content_scripts` or via browser.tabs.insertCSS.

Comment: My css is in content_scripts key of manifest, otherwise it wouldn't work. The thing is it ends up in dom either way and  at the end of the day the page where content script is activated has to download fonts.

Comment: My idea was to embed the font inside the css file, which is added not as DOM, but as a CSS content script described in my comment above.